# Correct UTC symbol alignment in ggplot legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, alignment, legend, symbols

I am trying to create a plot with ggplot, I have created the view that I want, however, it requires the use of 8 (\u) and 16 bit (\U) UTC symbols in the legend key elements. When I include both in the legend, the \U type symbol is misaligned compared to the others.  An example plot is included.

If someone could tell me how I vertically align the symbols in the legend correctly, I should be very grateful.

I am using Windows 10.

I have tried various remedies, including `label.vjust` varied for individual symbols, dual UTC ("\uD83C\uDD54") instead of the \U configuration, and using a mono spaced font, with no success.

Sample plot showing legend with misaligned symbols (cf. circled "E" compared to the others):
[image: Sample Plot showing misaligned symbols (cf. circled "E" compared to the others)]

This is the sample data to reproduce the plot.

```r
Name    SourceNo    SourceNoP   Source  MeanVal
C   0   E   Exam    19.96
C   10  10  x16 36.20
C   2   2   x4  17.57
C   12  12  x8  23.11
C   9   9   x14 2.76
C   4   4   x15 22.84
C   14  14  x1  9.00
F   0   E   Exam    44.40
F   2   2   x4  24.96
F   6   6   x7  35.54
F   13  13  x2  6.72
A   0   E   Exam    40.24
A   2   2   x4  23.73
A   16  16  x6  37.60
A   9   9   x14 13.12
G   0   E   Exam    29.88
G   7   7   x3  37.10
G   16  16  x6  35.50
G   6   6   x7  38.70
G   9   9   x14 20.02
B   0   E   Exam    34.06
B   2   2   x4  32.30
B   6   6   x7  27.52
H   0   E   Exam    44.40
H   2   2   x4  40.41
H   7   7   x3  44.20
H   15  15  x5  37.20
H   16  16  x6  34.25
H   6   6   x7  29.47
H   5   5   x9  38.00
H   11  11  x10 45.05
H   8   8   x11 41.70
H   8   8   x11 41.70
H   3   3   x12 27.08
H   9   9   x14 8.32
H   13  13  x2  23.92
E   0   E   Exam    37.67
E   2   2   x4  22.78
E   1   1   x13 23.45
E   4   4   x15 12.27
J   0   E   Exam    42.40
J   2   2   x4  34.56
J   16  16  x6  38.90
J   12  12  x8  26.18
J   4   4   x15 38.05
D   0   E   Exam    38.99
D   2   2   x4  19.51
D   16  16  x6  28.90
D   11  11  x10 26.25
D   9   9   x14 6.52
```

This is the R code I used.

```r
    library (ggplot2)
    library(paletteer)

    ## edit this to use the table of data below
    CoData <- read_excel(paste(Dir,xlsname,sep=""),
        sheet = "x", range = "A1:F50")  
    CoData$SourceF <-
        factor(CoData$Source,levels=unique(CoData$Source\[order(CoData$SourceNo)\]))
    CoData <- arrange(CoData,SourceNo)

    ## UTC codes: \\u2776 - circled 1 negative; \\U1F154 - circled e negative\*\*

    ShapeList  <- c("\\U1F154","\\u2776","\\u2777","\\u2778","\\u2779","\\u277A",
                    "\\u277B","\\u277C","\\u277D",
                    "\\u277E","\\u277F","\\u24EB","\\u24EC","\\u24ED",
                    "\\u24EE","\\u24EF","\\u24F0")

    CoDPlot <- ggplot(CoData, aes(x=Name,y=MeanVal)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour=SourceF), size=18,
    position=position_jitter(w=0.3, h=0, seed=1), alpha=0.8) +
    geom_text(aes(label=SourceNoP), colour="white", size=10,
    position=position_jitter(w=0.3, h=0, seed=1), alpha=0.8) +  
    geom_vline(xintercept=1.5:10.5, colour='white') +
    xlab("Name List") + ylab("Mean Compared Value") +
    guides(colour=guide_legend(title="Sources", nrow=3, 
      label.position = "bottom",
    override.aes=list(alpha=0.8, byrow=FALSE, size=12, shape=ShapeList))) +
    scale_color_paletteer_d("ggsci::default_ucscgb") +
    theme(
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        legend.key.size = unit(0.8,"lines"),   # line spacing in legend
        legend.position="bottom",
        legend.margin=margin(l = 1, unit='cm'))

    CoDPlot
```